# Loading variwide chart from Highcharts library in Angular 2+

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

I am trying to plot [variwide chart](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/variwide-chart) in angular 2+.

Till now i was plotting charts using

`const Highcharts = require('highcharts/highstock.src');`

how do I import variwide module of highcharts in this way?

I tried doing this.

`const Variwide = require('highcharts/modules/variwide')`

still it gives Highcharts [17 error](https://www.highcharts.com/errors/17).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From official docs: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/install-from-npm

```
var Highcharts = require('highcharts/highstock');

// Load **** as a module
require('highcharts/modules/variwide')(Highcharts);
```